# Targeting Facebook like button

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook, plugins

Im using the Facebook Button by BestWebSoft plugin in my WP site.

I'm trying to style the Facebook like button. Just want to make it bigger. Using my browser I see this rule for the like button that controls the size.

```
._2tga._49ve {
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 11px;
height: 20px;
padding: 0 0 0 2px
}
```

I can't seem too change it. I've the "custom code" tab in the product settings, my child theme style sheet with !important, an internal style sheet in the head and even looked for the code in the plugin files, but nothing is working.

Can anyone help with this? Here is the page the FB like button is on: http://vote.krankgolf.com Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to change the appearance: https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts

> Don't: Modify Facebook brand assets in any way, such as by changing the design or color

You can only use the Like Button just like you get it, but there is an option to make it larger in the Like Button generator: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Example:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-size="large" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, however if you read my post, the only thing I want to do is make the like button bigger. This is with-in the Facebook guidelines for presenting their logo.

Comment: that would be "changing the design" in my opinion ;) - either way, it is not possible and definitely not allowed to change the appearance in any way.

Comment: btw, there is an option to use a larger version. i have added that info to my answer.

Comment: Thanks that did exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated!

Comment: you are welcome. don´t forget to accept my answer ;)